# Best way to select the total count in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find the total count of rows in SQL Server.
Below query returns me 1 in all rows.
Can I use sub query to calculate the RowCounts Column? Will this affect the performance?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS RowCounts FROM Questions Where GroupID = @GroupID 
GROUP BY QuestionID, QuestionTitle, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, Answer, GroupID, Explanation, SubjectID
```

Comment: Not sure what you are after but based on your problem description you can get a count like this `SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCounts FROM Questions`. Notice there are no columns which will ensure that there is no grouping which is what you would want.

Comment: you want to have that count as a part of each row?

Comment: I want other columns too

Comment: `I want other columns too` <= You would only return the "other columns" with a `COUNT` if you wanted to get count statistics on those column values like number of times a questiontitle occurs.

Comment: I think a cross join of the count with your usual query should have a minimal performance impact compared to a subquery.

Comment: I want to have the total number of rows as part of my data selected.
Means If I have 5 total rows selected, Count should show 5 in all rows as a seperate column

Answer (score 2):

You need a window function

```
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY QuestionID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS RowCounts 
  FROM Questions
```

Comment: Is this window functions faster than subquery ?

Comment: give it a try: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON; SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM Questions) FROM Questions`

Comment: No need for `ORDER BY`  and `ROWS` to get a global count: `COUNT(*) OVER ()` returns the same

Comment: @dnoeth I did not know, I saw it in Gordons answer for the first time

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the total count, you can use this window function:

```
SELECT q.*, COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowCounts
FROM Questions q
WHERE GroupID = @GroupID ;
```

Window functions are usually more optimized than a separate `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

If you wanted to *enumerate* the output rows, I would recommend `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT q.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seqnum
FROM Questions q
WHERE GroupID = @GroupID ;
```